# как отсортировать словарь по дню даты рождения

Tags: python, словари

```
birthdays = {"Иванов Иван Иванович": datetime.date(1989, 5, 1), "Петров Петр Петрович": datetime.date(1998, 5, 5), "Василий Петр Петрович": datetime.date(1991, 5, 4), "Антон Петр Петрович": datetime.date(1990, 5, 29)}
```

способ ниже сортирует по году рождения

```
birthday2 = sorted(birthdays.items(), key=lambda d: d[1])
```

а мне нужно именно по дню

Comment: @LevTikhonov вы какую-то чушь написали.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Необходимо в функции указать что Вы хотите сортировать по дню:

```
birthday2 = sorted(birthdays.items(), key=lambda d: d[1].day)
```

Comment: Гиганское вам спасибо!!! я только учусь, и с этой мелочью два дня уже вожусь)))

Comment: @ВладиславКо, если ответ вам помог, отметьте его как принятый (галочка слева). Это поможет и ответившему и вам